# TRUNCATE command in Spark 2.2 Scala drops the SAP HANA Table instead of truncating

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hana

I'm trying to truncate a table in SAP HANA and insert data into it using Spark Scala.
However, 
when i run the script, my SAP HANA table gets dropped (instead of being truncated) and the 
code fails with below JDBC error.

As prescribed I'm using the .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("truncate","true") to avoid the dropping of table but it's not functioning as mentioned in the document.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Code :

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.hadoop._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
val url = "jdbc:sap://xx.xxx.xx:xx"
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("driver", "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver")
prop.setProperty("user", "MYSCHEMA")
prop.setProperty("password", "XXXXX")
val query1 = spark.read.jdbc(url,"MYSCHEMA.PH_SPARK_TRUNCATE",prop)
query1.createOrReplaceTempView("query1_view")
val query1out = spark.sql("select * from query1_view limit 1")
query1out.write.format("jdbc").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("truncate","true")
.option("driver", "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver")
.option("url", "jdbc:sap://xx.xxx.xx:xx")
.option("dbtable", "MYSCHEMA.PH_SPARK_TRUNCATE")
.option("user", "MYSCHEMA")
.option("password","XXXXX")
.save()
```

ERROR :

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [264] (at 39): invalid datatype: TEXT type is not supported for row table: line 1 col 40 (at pos 39)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:191)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:42)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.HReplyPacket._buildExceptionChain(HReplyPacket.java:973)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.HReplyPacket.getSQLExceptionChain(HReplyPacket.java:158)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.HPartInfo.getSQLExceptionChain(HPartInfo.java:40)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB._receive(ConnectionSapDB.java:3115)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.exchange(ConnectionSapDB.java:1518)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB._executeDirect(StatementSapDB.java:1419)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB._execute(StatementSapDB.java:1398)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB._execute(StatementSapDB.java:1383)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB._executeUpdate(StatementSapDB.java:1371)
  at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.executeUpdate(StatementSapDB.java:174)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:805)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
  ... 72 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that a row store table should be created with a column of data type `TEXT`. That's not supported with HANA.

From the stack trace, it looks like Spark is trying to create a table to store the result of a query execution. I guess that it does not indicate the type of table in the `CREATE TABLE` SQL command, which means HANA will choose the *default table type*.
Up until HANA 2 SP04, the default table type configuration parameter is `ROW`.

As this is not the best choice in most cases, the recommended solution here is to change the default table type parameter to `COLUMN`.

I don't know if and how that impacts Spark's behaviour concerning truncate and delete of tables, but it should get rid of the error message you posted.

Comment: Thank you Lars. Actually, I have created a column table only which supports TEXT Datatype. I guess the issue here is when I set Truncate=True the table in hana should get truncated. But in my case spark is dropping the table and recreating a row table and trying to put TEXT Data in it.